# Django: 'Data' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to save two `int` values into my *postgreSQL* database and am coming up show with the following traceback: `'Data' object has no attribute 'save'`. I can't figure out what is wrong.

***My Models...***

```
from django.db import models

class Data(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    curr_time = models.IntegerField()
```

***My Views...***

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
from models import Data

class Data(View):
    def get(self, request, date, val):
        data = Data(value=int(val), curr_time=int(date))
        data.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 111})
```

I have looked up and down Stack Overflow and haven't found any answers. Anyone see anything glarringly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `view` class's name and `model` class's name are same. Change the `view` class's name to something else i.e: `DataView`

Comment: Actually it was the opposite :) I answered before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change the name of the view!

```
from models import Data

class Data(View):   # oops, name clash
    ...
```

The class definition name stomped on the imported name `Data`.

Comment: I upvoted you. The other guy got in 1 minute beffore.